# how to use regex in the following string to avoid some specific character

Tags: regex

```
"{"key1":val1,"key1":val1,"key3":val3,"key4":val4}"
```

how to get val3 using regex without using double quotation mark ("").

I want to get value of "key3" using regex so I did something like this

```
'"key3":([^,]+)')
```

but I need to avoid double quotation mark ("") in this regex which is creating problem in defining this regex as string.

Comment: Why not simply parse the json? What language are you using?

Comment: this is a column in database which has datatype as text... so can't parse it... I am writing a dbm query which will take val3 as substring               using regex

Comment: which language you are using Ruby,Python etc ? what ?

Comment: it's postgres database query ... i want to get substring which can be done using regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on your question, but I *think* you are asking how to incorporate double quotes in a string which is specified using double quotes.  If that's what you mean, you can use double quotation marks in your string by escaping it.  Ex your regex could be `"\"key1\": \([^,]+\)"`

Another possible interpretation of your question is to completely avoid double quotes in the pattern (in fact, upon rereading this now sounds like your intention).  That could be done with something like this: `".*key3..([^,]+),.*"`

Comment: I did that but the same query can not be fired on database as backslash (\) will create a problem. I need to somehow avoid "".

Comment: `(?<=\"key3\":).+?(?=,|\})` will also extract *only* the value if that's all you're after. Why not simply wrap your json in single quotes?

Comment: I am looking to avoid "" in the regex

Comment: Edited with no-quote version

Answer (score 1):

```
/key3.:([^,]+)/
```

http://rubular.com/r/XCTRWtQ3im

In the regex above, the `.` matches one char which in this case matches the `"`.